# Flutter List View error in building list view

Tags: dart, flutter

I get an error while I'm building the ListView, At first I thought the API wasn't returning anything but I printed the movies variable in flutter and it consoled log the values.
Btw I'm trying to recreate this project:

https://github.com/mlabouardy/flutter-watchnow

The error I get is:

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

This is the list view builder:

```
class TopMoviesState extends State<TopMovies> {
  List<Movie> _movies = new List();
  final _apiGatewayURL = "https://gfioehu47k.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/staging/main";

  Widget _fetchMovies() {
    return new ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, i){
          return new Card(
              child: new Container(
                  height: 250.0,
                  child: new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: new Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Align(
                              child: new Hero(
                                  child: new Image.network("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+this._movies[i].getPoster()),
                                  tag: this._movies[i].getTitle()
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                            ),
                            new Expanded(
                                child: new Stack(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Align(
                                        child: new Text(
                                          this._movies[i].getTitle(),
                                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                      ),
                                      new Align(
                                        child: new Padding(
                                            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                            child: new Text(
                                                this._movies[i].getOverview(),
                                                maxLines: 8,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                      ),
                                      new Align(
                                        child: new Text(
                                          this._movies[i].getReleaseDate(),
                                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                      ),
                                    ]
                                )
                            )
                          ]
                      )
                  )
              )
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

This is how I'm running through each value I'm getting from the API:

```
void _addMovie(dynamic movie){
this._movies.add(new Movie(
    title: movie["title"],
    overview: movie["overview"],
    poster: movie["poster_path"],
    releaseDate: movie["release_date"]
));
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    http.get(this._apiGatewayURL)
        .then((response) => response.body)
        .then(json.decode)
        .then((movies) {
      movies.forEach(_addMovie);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not specifying an `itemCount` to `ListView`. So if you ever have enough space to display more then the number of items available, you'll try to access `_movies` at an invalid index. Resulting in this error.

Try to add

```
new ListView(
   ...
   itemCount: _movie.length
```

Comment: That does get rid of the error however, nothing is displayed

Comment: Because you have nothing loaded. You may need to call `setState`

Comment: what about list with dynamic items ?

Comment: im facing the same problem , i did mention itemcount but for some reason it only displays first 20 elements

Comment: great explanation.  So many answers in code similar to yours.  But the idea of accessing a collection instead of document at invalid index solved it for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add item count

```
new ListView(
   ...
   itemCount: _movie.length
```

without it `ListView.Builder` not know the position of list and and we are not showing the list according to position

Comment: im facing the same problem , i did mention itemcount but for some reason it only displays first 20 elements

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the index of listview.builder, 
Listview.builder is used for a very long or unknown set of lists, which you are doing correct.
Just count the number of values you are getting from the API response and add the index as a parameter.

For more reference, check this URL:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html